# Camel JMS Component

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel JMS component.
with connection pool of 20 and maxActiveSessionPerConnection 20

I have 6 JMS routes with each have concurrent consumer 5.

now question 6 camel routes create 6 new connection from POOL or share one connection ? If they share one connection then total session needed 6*5 = 30 .
But in my above config maxActiveSessionPerConnection is 20 so will this leave 
consumer to waiting state ? If yes what should I do make each route take independent connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each queuing system works slightly differently.  I would look up the documentation for the implementation you are attempting to work with.  If its ActiveMQ you can find that documentation here: http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html

Based off your question I would recommend attempting to setup the following:

I would setup the pool be standalone from the JmsComponents and then re-use that pool for every JmsComponent that you want to share the connections with.

Comment: But my question is
For each route like <from uri="jms:<Queue>" />
Do I have to create new JMS component, If have 10 routes means 10 JMS component required which share stand alone connection pool ?

Comment: You could reuse the same jms component, but I would strongly recommend isolating them for tuning reasons.  even isolating the pools if you need very fast results.